# mysql query returning me multiple results

Tags: mysql

I have the following query and it is returning me 360 records with duplicates, even if I added distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
leads.FirstName,
leads.LastName,
calls.callDate,
calls.callstatus,
calls.calllog,
calls.whoCalled,
notes.Notes,
notes.`TimeStamp`,
messages.sentDate,
messages.`subject`,
messages.greeting,
messages.message,
messages.toEmail,
messages.whoSent
FROM
leads  
left JOIN calls ON calls.LeadID = leads.LeadID 
right join notes on leads.LeadID = notes.LeadID 
right join messages on leads.LeadID = messages.LeadID where leads.leadid = 208
```

`select * from notes where leadid = 208` - it has 3 records:

`select * from messages where leadid = 208` it has 15 records

`select * from calls where leadid = 208` it has 8 records

Comment: 3 × 15 × 8 = 360 records.

Comment: Do you really need all those returning in your selection?

Comment: Use `group by` to eliminate duplicates

Comment: You're asking for a cartesian join of all calls, notes and messages for your lead.

Answer (score 0):

Modify `where` clause to get rid of NULL values of joined tables

```
WHERE calls.LeadID IS NOT NULL AND notes.LeadID IS NOT NULL AND 
messages.LeadID IS NOT NULL AND leads.leadid = 208
```

Comment: managed to fix, used the union to call 3 tables and named the columns as same using alais and '' as for missing columns from one table or another. and added a last column as tablename which carries the tablename name so to correctly display the dataa.